# How to change type of Add-to-Cart button?

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I am having problems with my `add to cart` button on product page. Its not submitting the form and it has been suggested that I should change the button type to fix this.

Here is the button code:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Basket</span></span></button>
```

How to fix the broken `add to cart` button?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the error log for error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all enable template path hint.

so you can check in which file you need to change code i think that file located in

app\design\frontend\themefolder\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml